# Need to populate countries list and respective states list in combo box

Tags: javascript, json, jquery, jsonp

Am looking for a Javascript API which would return all the country details and state details in JSON / JSONP format.

I searched a lot and couldnt get any such API service.

Can you please help me on this ??

I got one URL with which am populating country list. am looking to get state-list for the select countries

```
function getCountryList(){
           $.ajax({
               dataType : "jsonp",
               url : "http://doctor2book.com/service1.svc/getallcountries?callback=?",
               async : false,
               success : function(data) {
                   $("#countrySelectBox").html("");

                   $.each(data.getcountrybyidResult,function(index, value){                    
                       $("#countrySelectBox").append("<option value='"+value.country_code+"'>"+value.country_name+"</option>");
                   });

                   sortSelectBox($('#countrySelectBox option')) ;

                   $("#countrySelectBox").prepend("<option value='' selected>Select a Country</option>");


               },
               error : function(errorData) {
                   alert("Error while getting Country data :: "+errorData.status);
               }
           });
    }
```

Comment: may be this will help.It's not an API , it's just a `JavaScript` file.
http://bdhacker.wordpress.com/2009/11/21/adding-dropdown-country-state-list-dynamically-into-your-html-form-by-javascript/

Comment: Harsha : Thanks for responding .. actually am looking for API only. just an ajax hit and i should get the values

Comment: Take a look: https://www.blackbaud.com/files/support/infinitydevguidemobile/Advanced/Subsystems/bbisweb-developer-help/content/restapi/countryapi.htm#Country/%7BId%7D/State

Comment: I had a look at the link. But i couldn't frame the URL with which i will do an ajax-call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet you can get the (static) list from somewhere in the internet. For countries, just google "ISO country list". States are more complicated (unless you only mean US states), but I bet they are somewhere.

As it is a quite static data, compile it into your own list and put it in a .js file, it will have lots of advantages

- faster to use (no need for extra connection). Even faster once the browser caches the .js file
- no dependency on a service that tomorrow may shut down.
- no need for the user to access the internet (if we are talking about deploying your app in a corporate intranet).

Answer (score 1):

This suits the need.

Country code and maxRows needs to be passed

http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON?country=IN&maxRows=10